# ReactJS with dynamic type objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am working on a project to convert some of the rails view layer to ReactJS. One of the challenge that I have is to render a list of dynamic type of objects (Objects are using STI).

for example, I am trying to render a bag of fruits, and each fruit has a specific partial views in rails. In rails, I would do

```
fruits.each do |fruit|
  #fruit.type could be orange, apple, banana, etc.
  render 'fruits/' + fruit.type
end
```

How do i do this in ReactJS? Is it possible?

Comment: You want to choose which component to render based on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an object.

```
var things = {
   foo: FooComponent, ...
};
```

And then get a component from that.

```
var key = 'foo';
var Component = things[key];

return <Component />
```

Note that the variable must start with an uppercase letter if you're using jsx, otherwise it will assume you mean the html element `<component></component>`.

Or don't use jsx here.

```
React.creatElement(things[key], null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information on *where* you need to do this, I'm going to assume you need it at render time, in which case: just do the same thing in JavaScript.

```
.....React.createClass({
  ...
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      fruits: this.props.fruits || []
    };
  },
  ...
  render: function() {
    var fruits = this.state.fruits.map(function(f) {
      return <li>{f.type}</li>;
    });
    return <ul>{fruits}</ul>;
  },
  ...
});
```